# How would you translate "feat." (featuring) in song titles to Russian?

Tags: лексикон, музыка

How do I translate "featuring", which is used to mention guest singers/musicians in song titles?

As in: Crystal Castles — Not In Love (feat. Robert Smith)

"X и Y – название песни" is obvious, I'd like to find an accurate translation.

Comment: Possibly, just use `c`: _Основной исполнитель - Название песни (с Еще одним исполнителем)_

Answer (score 7):

I would say *при участии*.

Something along the lines of:

> ВИА "Кристал Каслз" при участии Роберта Смита, композиция "Никто мне не люб".

Comment: Also, "с участием".